# Use Arduino Libraries in PlatformIO?

Tags: arduino-ide, library

I'd like to use Arduino libraries installed in C:\Users\Username\Documents\Arduino\libraries in a PlatformIO project. Is it possible? if so, how?

Comment: I'd start with documentation, for example `lib_extra_dirs` looks promising